# Concatenate 2000 lines into 1 line in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have 2000 lines of code that I need to concatenate, hopefully into
one.

I know that in Emacs, with the `replace-string` command, I can add the
`+` for concatenation at the back of each line all in one go. But I
when I do this I constantly get a syntax error when I'm using the file
on SAGE. So I started experimenting and found that if I move them all
together on the same line and add the `+` symbol, it then works.
What's the best solution to put them all together on one line?

It might be because I have brackets within brackets in each line. Here
are three example lines from my output:

```
[[['37a1', 1], 153, 160, [[13, 2], [53, -1], [67, 2], [127, -1], [443, -1], [547, 2], [599, -1]]], [['43a1', 1], 159, 163, [[5, -1], [103, -1], [127, -1], [541, -1]]], [['53a1', 1], 159, 161, [[71, -1], [97, -1]]], [['57a1', 1], 155, 157, [[5, 2], [11, -1]]], [['58a1', 1], 152, 157, [[31, 2], [53, -1], [109, -1], [673, -1], [739, -1]]], [['61a1', 1], 157, 161, [[7, -1], [13, -1], [71, 2], [113, -1]]], [['65a1', 1], 159, 160, [[43, 2]]], [['77a1', 1], 155, 160, [[5, 2], [31, -1], [71, -1], [179, -1], [223, -1]]], [['79a1', 1], 156, 159, [[41, 2], [83, 2], [131, 2]]], [['82a1', 1], 150, 154, [[5, 2], [229, 2], [283, 2], [499, 2]]]]
[[['112a1', 1], 155, 156, [[5, -1]]], [['117a1', 1], 155, 157, [[11, 2], [523, 2]]], [['118a1', 1], 158, 161, [[127, -1], [251, -1], [277, -1]]], [['121b1', 1], 82, 82, []], [['122a1', 1], 151, 158, [[5, -1], [43, 2], [79, -1], [113, -1], [191, -1], [241, 2], [523, -1]]], [['123a1', 1], 157, 159, [[5, 0], [7, 2]]], [['123b1', 1], 156, 159, [[17, 2], [29, -1], [811, -1]]], [['124a1', 1], 155, 155, []], [['128a1', 1], 161, 162, [[13, 2]]], [['129a1', 1], 160, 163, [[283, -1], [563, -1], [659, -1]]]]
[[['130a1', 1], 158, 159, [[43, 2]]], [['131a1', 1], 161, 163, [[59, 0], [271, -1]]], [['135a1', 1], 151, 158, [[19, -1], [53, 2], [151, -1], [241, -1], [421, -1], [607, -1], [613, -1]]], [['136a1', 1], 160, 161, [[5, 2]]], [['138a1', 1], 155, 157, [[11, 2], [313, 2]]], [['141a1', 1], 154, 159, [[7, 0], [29, -1], [37, -1], [97, -1], [557, -1]]], [['141d1', 1], 159, 161, [[37, -1], [619, -1]]], [['142a1', 1], 152, 157, [[5, -1], [13, -1], [131, -1], [233, 2], [907, 2]]], [['142b1', 1], 158, 160, [[31, 0], [911, -1]]], [['143a1', 1], 155, 159, [[7, 2], [29, 2], [113, -1], [509, 2]]]]
```

So what I want is something like

```
A = B + C + D + ... = [a, b, c, ...] + [d, e, f, ...] + ...
```

where

```
[['37a1', 1], 153, 160, [[13, 2], [53, -1], [67, 2], [127, -1], [443, -1], [547, 2], [599, -1]]]
```

is one example of such an entry `a` and `B`, `C`, `D` are the set of
entries of lines 1, 2 and 3 (and I have 2000 of such lines).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Sage, but it's based on Python, right?  Valid Python syntax would be parens around the whole expression.  Then you can have a multiline expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go from

```
A
B
C
```

to

```
A+B+C
```

You could replace line endings with +'s:

<kbd>M-x replace-string</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-q C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

...and then manually fix-up the start and end of the resulting single line as necessary to meet the needs of a proper SAGE statement.

Comment: I've already done that. Apparently I need to also add \ after +

Comment: "\" after "+" would yield something like `A+\B+\C`.  Are you saying that's what Sage requires?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this but a simple one is keyboard macros.

Move to the first line.  Use `C-x (` to start a keyboard macro.

Then `C-e C-k` to join the next line to the current line.

Now `C-x )` to end the keyboard macro.

Now you can run it as much as you want: `M-1000 C-x e`.

If you want to more easily limit it you can narrow the buffer to the area you want to operate on.